# AJAX call not passing latest value for serverside processing

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have written a minimal server side processing script for datatables v1.10.0. The server requires the product id for getting records from database, it gets it from `select2` plugin based selector selection. The ajax call always passes the value first sent by it, a behavior reminiscent of cached data.

```
var table = $('#emails_table');
table.dataTable (
    {
        aoColumns: [
        {
            sClass: "center",
            mRender: function (data)
            {
                if (data == '1')
                {
                    return '<input name="row_check" type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" checked="checked" value="1">';
                }
                else if (data == '2')
                {
                    return '<input name="row_check" type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" checked="" value="0">';
                }
            },
            sWidth: '24px',
            bAutoWidth: false,
            bSortable: false },
        {   bSortable: true  },
        {   bSortable: true  },
        {   bSortable: true  },
        {   bSortable: true  }
        ],
        pagelength: 10,
        pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
        language:
        {
            lengthMenu: "  _MENU_ records",
            paginate:
            {
                previous:"Prev",
                next:"Next",
                last:"Last",
                first:"First"
            }
        },
        aoColumnDefs : [
        {
            orderable : false,
            aTargets : [0]
        }],
        order : [],
        processing : true,
        serverSide : true,
        deferRender : true,
        iDeferLoading : 0,
        ajax :
        {
            type : "POST",
            url  :  '<?php echo get_records_url(); ?>',
            data : {product : $('#product_search option:selected').val()} // this doesn't get the latest value
        }
    });

$("#show_emails").click(function ()
    {
        table.dataTable().fnClearTable(0);
        table.dataTable().fnDraw();
    });
```

The button is to be pressed before getting records based upon newer value of product. Setting up an alert in the `show_emails` button shows the change of value on different selection but ajax still sends the first ever value.

I have also tried this with a variable and refreshing its value in the button's click event to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing the following changes;

#### AJAX Call

```
ajax :
{
    type : "POST",
    url  :  '<?php echo site_url(); ?>',
    data : function (d)
           {
               d.product = $('#product_search option:selected').val();
           }
}
```

#### Button click event

```
$("#show_emails").click(function ()
{
    table.api().ajax.reload();
});
```